# Switch LED on STM discovery board with external button

Tags: stm32, microcontroller

I am new to programming microcontrollers.
I have the STM32F072 discovery board and I want to use an external push button with it. I am using Visual Studio Code.
I connected the button to the 3V output and the other side to pin A10, which is configured like this:

```
  /*Configure GPIO pin : PA10 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_10;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);
```

Then, I wrote a function to read the state of the button

```
uint8_t read_button(void)
{
    uint8_t button_state = HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_10);

    return button_state;
}
```

I am calling the function in the infinite while loop in main.c, where my idea was quite simply:

```
button_state = read_button();
if (button_state == 1)
{
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_6, GPIO_PIN_SET);
}
```

(Pin C6 is connected with with the red LED) After Building and upoading, the red LED is always on. The Button does nothing.
Can anyone give me a hint what am I doing wrong?
Thank you very much!

Comment: How do you think will the level at PA10 be sensed as "low"? Do you have an external pulldown resistor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's normal that  the LED is always on, you never put it off in your code.

```
button_state = read_button();
if (button_state == 1)
{
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_6, GPIO_PIN_SET);
} 
else
{
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_6, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
}
```

With this, your LED will be on when you push your button and off otherwise.